# How to pass user defined strructure array in ATL?

Tags: c++, com, atl

It may be a very simple question but I am not able to find a good documentation for it.

I have a ATL exe written in C++. One of the method in the exe should be able to return an array of user defined structures to the caller. Client is implemented in C/C++.

I was hoping that following code will do the trick but it fails to build - error C2039: 'type' : is not a member of 'ATL::_ATL_AutomationType' on CComSafeArray out_sa;

Can anyone suggest a way to achieve this or point me to any relevant documentation ?

```
typedef struct V3D
{
    double X;
    double Y;
    double Z;
} V3D;


typedef struct V3
{
    int X;
    int Y;
    int Z;
} V3;

typedef struct Sample3D
{
    struct V3D Sample3D;
    struct V3 Sample;
} Sample3D;


STDMETHODIMP CSimpleObject::StuctArray(LONG iNumber, VARIANT* MyObjArray)
{
    int i = 0;
    Sample3D *pSample3D = NULL;
    _ATLTRY
    {
        ATLENSURE_THROW(MyObjArray, E_POINTER);
        VariantInit(MyObjArray);

        pSample3D = new Sample3D[iNumber];

        for (i = 0; i < iNumber; ++i) {
            pSample3D[i].Sample3D.X = i;
            pSample3D[i].Sample3D.Y = i;
            pSample3D[i].Sample3D.Z = i;
            pSample3D[i].Sample.X = i;
            pSample3D[i].Sample.Y = i;
            pSample3D[i].Sample.Z = i;
        }

        CComSafeArray<Sample3D> out_sa;

        ATLENSURE_SUCCEEDED(out_sa.Create(iNumber));

        for (i = 0; i < iNumber; ++i) {
            out_sa.SetAt(i, pSample3D[i]);
        }
        ATLVERIFY(SUCCEEDED(CComVariant(out_sa).Detach(MyObjArray)));
    }
    _ATLCATCH(Exception)
    {
        return Exception;
    }
    return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: To store a user-defined struct inside a `SAFEARRAY`, you have to custom marshal the struct data, either by implementing the `IRecordInfo` interface, or just copy the struct's raw bytes into a `SAFEARRAY` using the `UI1` type.

Comment: [Passing a Safearray of UDTs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221212.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, I am working on it. Once resolved I will post the complete code.